# WISE - COM Server registration option "Do not register" doesn't work?

Tags: delphi, com, wise

I created an installer in wise, for a Delphi application which using an in-proc (DLL) COM-Server. 
I configured the DLL in the Wise project as "Do not register", but after a test installation it is registered anyway?

[image]

Is this an "undocumented feature" of WISE or am I doing something wrong?

Does anyone have a workaround or a fix for this issue?

P.S. The reason that I don't want to register the DLL is that on target PC that COM server already may be registered for another application with specific settings (threading model, path, etc) which I don't want to touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution or workaround (possible because I did't understand it till the end, but it's working).

COM DLL will be registered on target PC, even if it is marked with "Do not register", in case if it is registered on deployment PC. 
Solution:

- unregistered DLL from local (deployment) PC
- Remove it from installation package, save (and compile) package
- re-Add COM DLL to package,  mark it with "Do not register", save and compile.

After these steps it works as expected - DLL is not registered on target PC.

It seems this is happening because of windows installer advertising (which still i didn't understand properly), but from WISE documentation I found:

> "How Self-Registration Information is Captured 
>     When you add a .DLL
>   or .OCX file containing COM self-registration information to an
>   installation, its registration information is scanned and the
>   appropriate registry keys are added to the installation. This system
>   of registration is more robust than letting the file self-register at
>   installation time because it does not depend on the presence of other
>   files on the destination computer or on how well the .OCX or .DLL file
>   adheres to self-registration conventions."

For this reason as additional measure, before above described steps, I changed WISE Advertising options:

[image: Wise > Tools > Options ... Advertising tab]

For `Advertising Setting:` selected `Do not scan advertising information` option.
Unchecked option `Automatically add self-registration`.

---

All this written is actual solution, but thanks to @Christopher Painter response I was introduced in "**DLL Hell**" terminology, especially for COM DLLs, so that as **LONG-TERM solution (in perspective)** i would check for **Registration-Free Activation of COM Components** ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)).

Comment: Yes, if you privately deploy your DLL and use RegFree COM  you've estentially isolated the component and deconflicted the DLL hell.  That would be a better design.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to avoid this turning into a "what tool should I use thread".  That said,  WiX/IsWiX is free open source and should meet your needs.  (It's hard to say for sure since I have no idea what other requirements this MSI would have.)

That said,  is there any chance that the DLL was already registered?  Are you testing on a snapshotted VM or other reproducible environment where you can be 100% certain that it was not?

If so, are there any other actions in the wise script that could be causing the registration to happen.  I'm not aware of a bug/feature in wise but if there is, you are SOL because that product has long been dead and there is no support or updates available.

One last note.  You're comment about the DLL might already be there and registered... that's called DLL hell.  What if it's not there... now you aren't registered.  You've got some design problems you need to resolve before you ever hope to have a high quality installation experience regardless of what tool you use.

Comment: if DLL is not registered, then current application will register it from its path. This is because it may be installed on a PC with another application (main application, since current is auxiliary tool) which already use and registered this DLL.

Comment: Yes i tested it both on real and virtual PCs where DLL was not registered at all or was unregistered before installation and got registered after... it seems this is wise "feature"

Comment: Or there's a separate action in the wise script you aren't accounting for.  Try creating a brand new script that does nothing but install that one file with no registration to confirm.  I think this all is wrong in the first place as I can think of many ways for this to fail.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your last sentence - can you please explain what exactly is wrong and what might to fail?
P.S. thanks for suggestion - I'll check it

Comment: A simple installation with single COM DLL - same result (it's registered even if I set to not register)

Comment: I've responded to my question with a solution which I found, BUT thanks for introducing me with "DLL Hell" term, which pushed me to think about "Registration-Free Activation of COM Components" solution.

Comment: Great.  That simplifies the story and WiX/IsWiX can easily handle that for you.

Comment: "WiX/IsWiX can easily handle that for you" - what exactly "that" do you mean?

Comment: One of your original comments was that you were requested to provide an MSI also.  WiX/IswiX are Free Open Source Software projects that can create an MSI.  WiX is the core tool and IsWiX authors WiX projects and provides an InstallShield like UI for WiX.  Since you have simplified the story to deploying a DLL and a manifest  it would be really easy to create an MSI.